# How to attach files stored in local store e.g application database folder to gmail

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I am unable to attach files stored in the database to gmail.
Using sdcard it works fine but I do not want to store those files in the sdcard.

I have seen links which suggest to use a Content provider but it works only for gmail and not any other clients.
http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/974

So could anybody let me know if there is any solution to attach files to gmail, email clients without storing those files in sdcard.

Thanks and Regards,
Ajay

Answer (score 1):

Here is solution for your question posted in comments section in http://stephendnicholas.com/archives/974.

Create another file based on cache file.

*

```
File shareFile = new File(getCacheDir() + File.separator + zip_filename);
shareFile.setReadable(true, false);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(shareFile));
```

*